# Problem with Caption of a Table

Tags: tables, captions

i am making a table in Latex. Everything is fine but the Caption section is not the way i want it to be. 
I want the whole caption of the table in one single line, Not in two lines, the way it is[image] right now as shown in the figure. I am doing it like this.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption {Parameters for Energy Model} 
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular} {|r|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Parameter}      &   \textbf{Value}   \\
\hline
Power in recieving      &    5W     \\
\hline
Power in sleep mode     &   250mW (assumed 5\% of $P_{Rx}$) \\
\hline
RF efficiency           &   20\%    \\
\hline
Supply loss efficiency  &   10\%    \\
\hline
Cooling efficiency      &   50\%    \\
\hline
Max transmit power      &   5W      \\
\hline
Wakeup Energy           &   50J     \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: The caption is in accordance of your document-class or you defined so at loading for example `caption` package. If the document-class is from some journal, which use for example`ieeetran`, than it is according to journal policy.

Comment: Yes i am using the IEEEtran document-class.

Comment: If you like to publish in some ieee journal, than don't touched this ... leave as it is!

Comment: Well i am very new to Latex, so that is why i am asking.
i am writing this paper for a conference, so am i using the write document class for a conference paper ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not bound to the journal's policy on how to set such things, you might want to load the package `caption` which 'fixes' this for you. Note that the font-size of the caption is getting slightly bigger than before. Please read the manual of `caption` in order to see how to tweak such things. In order to change something just for the tables, it would look like `\captionsetup[table]{...}`. **Edit:** I inserted something which comes close to the default.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font={small,sc},labelsep=colon}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption {Parameters for Energy Model} 
        \footnotesize
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value} \\
            \midrule
            Power in recieving & \SI{5}{\watt} \\
            Power in sleep mode & \SI{250}{\milli\watt} (assumed \SI{5}{\percent} of $P_{Rx}$) \\
            RF efficiency & \SI{20}{\percent} \\
            Supply loss efficiency & \SI{10}{\percent} \\
            Cooling efficiency & \SI{50}{\percent} \\
            Max transmit power & \SI{5}{\watt} \\
            Wakeup Energy & \SI{50}{\joule} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, how can now i add the left and right side boarder lines. Don't like the open ended table

Comment: @AftabAhmedKhan You are welcome. About the borders: Just use the table you have provided above. But do not use `center` here.